# Multi Screen Rendering in Unity

Tags: unity, rendering

My experience with Unity in not that in depth. But I am wondering if it possible in unity to split what is being rendered across multiple screens.

It's hard to explain, so here is an image: 
[image]

So while the middle screen is fine to render, I want to spread the image all around the player. That is both to the side and, the bottom and top of the player.

Is such a thing possible? Has anyone ever done something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity doesn't support rendering to multiple targets, which leaves 2 options:

1. Render a single really-wide image, and use a screen-splitter (such as the [Matrox TripleHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/displayport/)) to drive 3 output devices
2. Link 3 computers together via local network.  Use the 1st computer to respond to user controls and send transform information to the second two computers.  The 2nd and 3rd computers just respond to the network transform information and render.  If your scene is interactive or otherwise nondeterministic, this can get complicated.

See also [this question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/9284/unity3d-to-cave-systems.html) which describes some middleware solutions for CAVEs.

Comment: Wow, so in other words, don't use Unity if you want to do this :)

Comment: Another option is to use any eyefinity card (last couple AMD cards), these are consumer hardware and have drivers which allow you to tell windows you have on screen the size of 3 (or 6 depending on the card) monitors. http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/Pages/eyefinity.aspx